# How to run windows-only forex application MetaTrader in Ubuntu?

Tags: wine

After checking some forex sites like AGEA - Trading and Investing site, they are giving good business but only run on windows. What I want to know is if there are any kind of forex business application which run under Ubuntu? What is the name of the platform and how do I join that business. I don't want to go back installing windows to make this business run with me.

[image: MetaTrader Platform]

Answer (score 4):

You can use Wine to run Windows-only Application within Ubuntu.

Wine supports MetaTrader and you would be able to run it fine. However, you would have to use the Development Version of Wine as `MetaTrader4` requires Wine 1.5.4 and `MetaTrader5` requires Wine 1.5.9. Look at [this link](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1599) which gives further information about running MetaTrader under Wine. The latest Wine Development Release is 1.5.20 and you should install this version for greater compatibility.

**Step 1** : Add Wine PPA to your software sources:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

**Step 2** : Update your software sources:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Step 3** : Install latest development release of Wine:

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

**Step 4** : Run the executable Setup File `*.exe` for your version of MetaTrader to install it as you normally do in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can run MT4/5 on ubuntu (as I do), you will run into issues with regards to rendering of icons/graphics, that is problematic in the linux world. My suggesting to you, is if you want to run something native on your laptop/desktop (without the use of a VPS), then try opening up a demo account with a broker that offers a web based platform.

Comment: I have used it on Ubuntu and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Crossover fits you better than Wine. [According with the official webpage](http://www.codeweavers.com/via/MetaTrader4/), crossover runs MetaTrader.

Ok, Crossover is not free software, but maybe for you is most straitforward solution.